# Is possible to "statically" check if a FQCN is of a given type in PHP?

Tags: php, reflection, types, instance

Would be possible to check *statically* (meaning without creating an instance) if a string containing a FQCN like `$fqcn`:

```
function checkCreatingInstance($fqcn)
{
    // Create a new instance
    $instance = new $fqcn;

    return ($instance instanceof 'MyNamespace\Entity\SendMessage');
}

function checkStatically($fqcn)
{
    /* TODO */
}

$fqcn = 'MyNamespace\Entity\SendSmallTextMessage';
var_dump(checkCreatingInstance($fqcn)); // true
```

Is of a given type? An example hierarchy:

```
namespace MyNamespace\Entity;

class SendMessage { /* Stuff */ }

namespace MyNamespace\Entity;

class SendNewsletter extends SendMessage { /* Stuff */ }

namespace MyNamespace\Entity;

class SendSmallTextMessage extends SendMessage { /* Stuff */ }
```

Comment: The reflection API might be capable of doing it, but I don't know for sure.  Still might be a good place to start looking for an answer though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. [`is_a()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-a.php) will do it, **if** you pass `TRUE` as the third argument.

[Example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/U0szGT)

The advantage of this is that you can write your function so it accepts and object or a string and it will work either way, you don't have to have two functions for a static and instantiated check:

```
function checkIsChildOf ($objOrFQCN, $parent)
{
    return is_a($objOrFQCN, $parent, TRUE);
}
```

Yet another example of the PHP manual being poor - this behaviour is documented in the manual, so far as I can tell but I have no clue why you didn't see it, so the manual is just poor to not make it visible.

Comment: @hakre Interesting edit... I said it was not documented because the documentation for `is_a()` states that the first parameter should be of type `object` rather than `mixed`. There is also nothing in the documentation that says "you can pass a string as the first argument and it will be treated as the name of a class". I suppose the fact that there is an `$allow_string` argument does *imply* that it will work, but I stand by the statement that it is not *explicitly* documented.

Comment: @DaveRandom: It's not that prominent, but it's written for the third parameter: *"If this parameter set to false, string class name as object is not allowed."* Could read: if true, it works. Anyway, it's not that well worded probably because of it being a later change. My english is not that well, but I try an edit. You do know you can edit those manual pages btw?

Comment: @hakre I did not until just now. I presume it is peer reviewed before it goes live?

Comment: @DaveRandom: Sure. Please try if this preview works for you: http://preview.php.net/manual/en/phdoe-1338978881-function.is-a.php?0.8551002277527004

Answer (score 2):

```
namespace Foo;

class A { }

class B extends A { }

class C { }

is_subclass_of('\Foo\A', '\Foo\A');  // false
is_subclass_of('\Foo\B', '\Foo\A');  // true
is_subclass_of('\Foo\C', '\Foo\A');  // false
```

http://php.net/is_subclass_of

Comment: Interesting - I don't really understand the difference between this and `is_a()` and the manual does not seem to adequately explain. +1 for a good working answer though.

Comment: `is_subclass_of` works like the name says, it returns `true` if and only if the class is a *sub*-class. `is_a` also returns `true` if the class is itself, i.e. the first case of `is_a('\Foo\A', '\Foo\A')` would also be `true`.